# MyLocationOverlay - Custom image, but no shadow

Tags: android, google-maps, mono, xamarin.android

I have an application, which uses a custom implementation of *MyLocationOverlay*.

In the implementation I set a Bitmap property that is used when it has been specified, by an overload of Draw.

It works nicely, using my custom image, **but it doesn't display a shadow** - as is done automatically in an *ItemizedOverlay*.

Can anyone help?

Here is (the relevant code from) my class:

```
public class LocationOverlay: MyLocationOverlay
{
    /// <summary>Bitmap to use for indicating the current fixed location.</summary>
    public Bitmap LocationMarker { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Uses the custom marker bitmap if one has been specified. Otherwise, the default is used.</summary>
    /// <param name="canvas"></param>
    /// <param name="mapView"></param>
    /// <param name="shadow"></param>
    /// <param name="when"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool Draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, bool shadow, long when)
    {
        var drawShadow = shadow;

        if (LocationMarker != null && LastFix != null)
        {
            var screenPoint = new Point();
            var geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(LastFix.Latitude * 1E6), (int)(LastFix.Longitude * 1E6));
            mapView.Projection.ToPixels(geoPoint, screenPoint);
            canvas.DrawBitmap(LocationMarker, screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y - 32, null);
            drawShadow = true;
        }

        base.Draw(canvas, mapView, drawShadow);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. You can use *DrawAt* to draw the shadow automatically.

So my property becomes a *Drawable* thusly:

```
public Drawable MarkerResource
{
    set
    {
        _locationMarker = value;
        var widthOffset = _locationMarker.IntrinsicWidth / 2;
        _locationMarker.SetBounds(-widthOffset, -_locationMarker.IntrinsicHeight, widthOffset, 0);
    }
}
```

And the override now looks like this:

```
public override bool Draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, bool shadow, long when)
{
    if (LastFix == null) return false;

    if (_locationMarker != null)
    {
        var screenPoint = new Point();
        var geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(LastFix.Latitude * 1E6), (int)(LastFix.Longitude * 1E6));
        mapView.Projection.ToPixels(geoPoint, screenPoint);
        DrawAt(canvas, _locationMarker, screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y, shadow);
    }
    else if (MyLocation != null) DrawMyLocation(canvas, mapView, LastFix, MyLocation, when);

    if (IsCompassEnabled) DrawCompass(canvas, Orientation);
    return false;
}
```

Works perfectly.

This also now respects enabling the compass and will draw using the default technique if no *Drawable* is specified.

Comment: I blogged about his [here](http://spiritmachineblog.tumblr.com/post/31148616147/customising-mylocationoverlay-in-mono-for-android), where you can see the full customised implementation of _MyLocationOverlay_.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the point of the shadow argument.  The map calls your draw() method twice and it tells you whether this is the shadow pass or not.  It doesn't draw the shadow for you.  So your code will look something like this:

```
public override bool Draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, bool shadow, long when)
{
    if (LocationMarker != null && LastFix != null)
    {
        var screenPoint = new Point();
        var geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(LastFix.Latitude * 1E6), (int)(LastFix.Longitude * 1E6));
        mapView.Projection.ToPixels(geoPoint, screenPoint);

        if(shadow)
        {
            // Draw your shadow bitmap here
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.DrawBitmap(LocationMarker, screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y - 32, null);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So there's no way to leverage an auto-drawn shadow like in ItemizedOverlay?