# Android - How to add shadow in a custom MyLocationOverlay

Tags: android, google-maps, mylocationoverlay

I want to add a shadow to a custom marker for MyLocationOverlay. I have tried this using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887532/mylocationoverlay-custom-image-but-no-shadow/10894663#10894663):

```
  @Override
  protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) {
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(myLocation, currentPoint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, currentPoint.x - this.markerBitmap.getWidth()/2, currentPoint.y - this.markerBitmap.getHeight(), null);
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {

      if (getLastFix() == null) {
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
      }

      if (markerDrawable != null) {
          GeoPoint lastFixGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(getLastFix().getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)(getLastFix().getLongitude() * 1E6));
          mapView.getProjection().toPixels(lastFixGeoPoint, currentPoint);

          drawAt(canvas, markerDrawable, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, shadow);
    } else if (getMyLocation() != null) {
        drawMyLocation(canvas, mapView, getLastFix(), getMyLocation(), when);
    }
      return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could draw a shadow to a custom marker for MyLocationOverlay, with the following:

```
@Override
protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) {
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(myLocation, currentPoint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(shadowBitmap, currentPoint.x - this.markerBitmap.getWidth()/2, currentPoint.y - this.markerBitmap.getHeight(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, currentPoint.x - this.markerBitmap.getWidth()/2, currentPoint.y - this.markerBitmap.getHeight(), null);
}
```

I hope this helps someone.